# Update GCC to the 6.3 version

Tags: apt, gcc, c++, versions, compiler

I want to use some C++ features only available in more recent versions of the language. The problem is Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet) has 4.9.2 installed and looking at the output I get from *apt-get install gcc*:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

It says it's already the newest version. I don't understand why...

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 is no longer supported, perhaps you should move to a newer version. Old versions of Ubuntu usually do not have the latest versions of packages, you have to upgrade the distribution or install your package from a ppa or build it from source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only option exist is to [Build it from Sources](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html), since you're running Vivid (15.04) version which has reached EOL (End Of Life).

1. Download the source code and its prerequisites:

   ```
   wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
   tar jxvf gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
   cd gcc-6.3.0
   ./contrib/download_prerequisites
   ```
2. Compile the sources (note: this command will differ depending on where you initially saved the .bz2 archive), you can also modify [option](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) for `build` command. In this case we'll use very basic option:

   ```
   cd ~
   mkdir gcc-build && cd gcc-build
   ../gcc-6.3.0/configure -v --prefix=$HOME/gcc-6.3.0
   ```

   **NOTE**: Make sure you have read the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html) to view available option.
3. Now we are ready to build gcc

   - Run `make` command to build gcc, this steps will take a long time to complete.

     ```
     make
     ```
   - Once the above phase is finished, you can install *built* gcc with:

     ```
     sudo make install
     ```

     Once this process has completed, run the command `gcc --version` to verify that the installation has completed successfully.

Comment: What does the "-v" option do? I can't seem to find it on https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: `-v` stand for `-verbose`.  [More information refer to what verbose really is](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/v/verbose-mode.htm)

Comment: To which folder is g++6.3 installed when following these steps? To `~/gcc-6.3.0`, to `~/gcc-build` or to some other folder? Shouldn't any of the folders that was created be removed after running these commands or are they all still required?

Comment: `tar xzvf gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2` just prints `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`; `tar: Child returned status 1`; `tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`, so I unpacked the archive with the archive manager.

Comment: When I run `../gcc-6.3.0/configure -v --prefix=$HOME/gcc-6.3.0`, I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory`, `/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc`, `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc` and similar errors.

Comment: Well that did not work.

Comment: This worked for me but I now have 2.4GB in my ~/gcc-6.3.0 directory... maybe a silly question but do I really need all of this, and is there a better place to put it?

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu 15.04 has reached *end of life* and has no support, which means no more updates or fixes *(security, bugs or features)* will be published.

You should update or reinstall with a newer Ubuntu version.

I'll recommend go with 16.10 *(9 month support)* which already has gcc 6.x branch on official repos.

But you also can go with 16.04 LTS *(5 year support)* and add a *untrusted/unguaranted ppa* to get latest gcc versions like [this one](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=xenial)

Personally, I would choose go with 16.10 and keep updating from official channels to later software/Ubuntu versions without adding *(mostly) any* ppa.