# GCC upgrade from 4.8 to 6.3 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, gcc

Followed the following procedure to upgrade my `gcc` from 4.8 to 6.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04, (as described by [Update GCC to the 6.3 version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864893/update-gcc-to-the-6-3-version/864900#864900) )

```
wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/gcc-6.3.0/gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
tar xzvf gcc-6.3.0.tar.bz2
cd gcc-6.3.0
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ~
mkdir gcc-build && cd gcc-build
../gcc-6.3.0/configure -v --prefix=$HOME/gcc-6.3.0
make -j16
sudo make install -j16
```

But I was not able to see the upgraded version of `gcc` when given `gcc -v`

Can anyone suggest a solution for this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You installed to `$HOME/gcc-6.3.0`. Is that directory in your `PATH`?

Comment: yes, $HOME points to my Home directory and I extracted the tar file too in my home directory only.

Comment: That's good, but not what I asked.

Comment: IIRC it would be `$HOME/gcc-6.3.0/bin` specifically that you would need to add to your `PATH`. Also you shouldn't need `sudo` to install to `$HOME` - however since you apparently *may* use `sudo`, you could consider installing from the [toolchain-r PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test?field.series_filter=trusty) instead.