# How can I install an older version (6.3) of GCC? I need it for MATLAB compatibility

Tags: 17.10, gcc, matlab

Hi guys I've seen similar questions but not even one fully answered, so here's mine:

I need to install an older version (6.3) of GCC than the one in my computer, i'm using Ubuntu 17.10 an my actual GCC verion is "gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2)".

I've heard that is possible to install more than one GCC version in the same computer, would you suggest it? If so how would i be able to choose when to use which?

Thanks for your attention! :)

Answer (score 2):

In standard Ubuntu repo you have various gcc versions. Simply type
`apt-get install gcc-6` to install gcc version 6.4.

Comment: cool but i need 6.3

Comment: gcc-6 v6.3.0 and gcc-6 v6.4.0 : No functional difference. From `gcc-6.4.0/NEWS` : This release is a bug-fix release, containing fixes for regressions in GCC 6.3 relative to previous releases of GCC.

Comment: @KnudLarsen OP can give it a try, but MATLAB has particular requirements for the compiler. Problem isn't in trying, problem is that software depends on other specific software versions :)

Comment: If 6.4 will not work (which should be checked since this is probably the safest solution) there are two other options: (1) https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/gcc-6.3 i.e., the backport of gcc 6.3 or (2) Build it from Sources https://askubuntu.com/questions/864893/update-gcc-to-the-6-3-version

Comment: Ok, this seems like the exact problem I also have, I need to compile the MATLAB interface of MUMPS, which is a sparse linear solver. 2018a version of MATLAB requires gcc 6.3. I added the above ppa but whatever I do, it is not possible to install the specific gcc-6.3 version, any ideas on how to continue further? BTW, I did not have the time to, yet, try to install from the source.

Comment: I recommend installing with aptitude instead of apt-get as this can help resolve the dependency issues.